# Access forbidden at Steampowers

Tags: blocked-services

I have a problem with http://www.steampowers.net: Every time I try to log in with Tor it shows me [this blocking page](http://www.steampowers.net/proxy.php). I want to login to do a survey, because I live in a poor country so there is literally no survey to do. How can I fix this?

Comment: the opposite
dont use proxy vpn and adblocker

Answer (score 1):

The error message is very clear: «You are not allowed to use Proxy/VPN»

Using Tor is similar to use a proxy, so they probably acted to block it.

So you would need to convince them to lift the block, although IMHO that seems unlikely.